# Issue while reading from XML file on sdcard

Tags: android, xml

Friends, I am facing an issue while reading information from a xml file located on the SD card.The code is being implemented successfully but there is nothing being displayed either on logcat nor there is no exception popping out. Please help me for the same.

```
public class History extends Activity
{
    private ListView lstv;

    static ArrayList<Records> arr;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);

        try {


            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/saved_images/history.xml"; 
            File file = new File(path);
            SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader reader=parser.getXMLReader();

            XMLHandler handler=new XMLHandler();

            //parser.parse(stream,handler);
            reader.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))));

            arr=handler.getArray();

            ArrayAdapter<Records> adpt=new ArrayAdapter<Records>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
            //lstv.setAdapter(adpt);                    

            handler.startDocument();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        ArrayList<Records> array;
        Records records ;
        String strCurrentValue = null;

        public ArrayList<Records> getArray() {
            return array;
        }

        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            super.startDocument();
            array=new ArrayList<Records>();
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String elementName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            super.startElement(uri, elementName, qName, attributes);

            if(elementName.equals("Record"))
            {
                records=new Records();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
            super.characters(ch, start, length);

            strCurrentValue=new String(ch, start, length);
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String elementName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
            super.endElement(uri, elementName, qName);
            if(elementName.equals("date"))
            {
                records.date=strCurrentValue;
            }else if(elementName.equals("cc"))
            {
                records.cc=strCurrentValue;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            super.endDocument();

            for(Records c:array)
            {
                Log.d("XmlHandler", c.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to see anything on log-cat or onto the screen. Please help me for the same code using snippets.
Thanks

Comment: You should avoid loading from disk or/and parsing on the main thread. Try to use AsyncTask if you don't want to face with ANR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your handler never actually adds the record to the array - looks like you need to include an action for the endElement of type 'Record' which adds it to the array.

Also as Giovanni says this entire piece of code will hold up the UI thread so if the XML file is non-trivial this should be handled in a separate thread with a progress dialog.

Comment: hey mate I did not get "an action for the endElement of type 'Record' which adds it to the array." Can you kindly elaborate it more please

Comment: But you should - you get (and process) a startElement for it in which you create the record. You need to find the matching endElement so that you can use that new record and add it to the array.